# How to customize the Properties of usercontrol in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have usercontrol called as 'DateControl1' in which i have textbox and a calenderextender(ajax).I have written a property for my usercontrol as follows:
 public string DateFormat
        {
            get { return dateformat; }
            set { dateformat = value; }
        }
when i assign the format in my cs file as DateControl1.DateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy", then this dateformat must be assigned to the built-in property of Calenderextender.Can anyone please tell how to do this in c# asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first time, when your user control is going to consume the calendar extender at that time make sure to pass your property value to the calendar extender.

//something like this
calext.DateFormat=DateFormat;

For an subsequent time,
You can use the setter of your DateFormat property to set the property of calendar extender if the calendar extender has already been consumed.

//something like this
public String DateFomat{
get{return dateformat;}
set{dateformat=value; if(calext!=null) calext.DateFormat=dateformat;}
}

Thanks,
Pranav Kaushik (http://www.pranavkaushik.wordpress.com)